# Get UTM regions overlapping with a geojson polygon

Tags: coordinate-system, sentinel-2, utm, web-mercator

how can I get the list of UTM grids overlapping with a geojson polygon in web mercator? I am trying to download data off of Sentinel, and I am seeing if I can go directly from an input polygon to downloading a tile off of the Sentinel bucket on AWS/GCloud.

My current workflow is to use `sentinelsat` to get the scenes, but I want to download the scenes directly from the bucket without any intermediary libraries, and knowing the UTM grids will help me get there.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the UTM Grid of a point using the expression:

```
zone_number = math.floor(((longitude + 180) / 6) % 60) + 1
```

and then look at the latitude to decide if it's north or south.

So, all you need to do is apply that formula to each corner of the polygon's bounding box and you'll be able to calculate the entire range covered.